# Assign file with no extension to a language on VS Code as default

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I usually open files that have no extension just `filename` . I know I can change the language syntax with *Change Language Mode --> Language that I want* but I don't want to do this manually every time I open such a file. Can I make a default to this language every time I open a file with no extension?

I know I can do this:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.myphp": "php"
}
```

But what if there is no extension? Also I want to be able to do this without affecting the other file types (that have extension).

Comment: Even better, file is read and automatically set to the contents...  , :O

Comment: `files.associations` uses glob patterns. With those you can normally match extensionless files with an inverted pattern such as `!(*.*)`. However, after a bit of digging through VSCode sources, it seems it uses simplified glob matching that doesn't support this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.21.1/src/vs/base/common/glob.ts#L430-L437 - Perhaps consider opening an issue on the VSCode repo?

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23873

Answer (score 9):

VS Code's globbing doesn't currently seem to have a way to detect files with no extension. Every time someone opens an issue, they point it back to [this issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1800). They detail their [globbing support here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#GlobPattern).

That said, I do have a hacky solution to this. Put this in your "WORKSPACE SETTINGS" (not your general settings unless you really want this to be global).

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "[!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php",
        "[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]": "php"
    },
}
```

This works by adding a rule for every file name length and ensuring that the file cannot have a period in it (up to 20 characters in my example). This is a horrible hacky solution, but if you hold your nose and set it once, you can forget it and things just work. I do this in my dotfiles repo to associate extension-less files with "shellscript".

You an also do this just for a specific directory by using the double star glob: `"**/just_this_dir_name/[!.]": "php"`.

Comment: I pinched my nose and put in the hack. Thank you so much, it works great! I could not get the one-liner for a specific directory to work though. How would that work with a file path like `bash/snippets/`? is that an absolute path or can it be relative to the opened workspace? I tried `/bash\/sinnpets` and that did not work either.

Comment: Try the star syntax -  `"**/bash/snippets/[!.]": "shellscript"`

Comment: Yeah is does not work. I am on vscode 1.52.1, WSL Ubuntu remote container.

Comment: Seems like you should ask a new question on stackoverflow related to your specific issue. Post the settings JSON you're using and you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the closing of issue [Expose 'change language' as command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1800) and the development of plugin [Modelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrislajoie.vscode-modelines), we can now use vim style modeline inside files without suffix and vscode can detect the file type.

Example:

filename: `post-commit`

file content:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# vim: set ft=sh

echo "hello world linked"
```

After installing the Modelines extension, the file is highlighted properly:

[image: sample highlight result]

Answer (score 0):

If you choose mattmc3's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53468881/5589126) you can use pattern-list entry to write it in one line:

```json
{
    "file.associations": {
        // all files up to 30 characters long without extension will be associated with `php`
        "{[!.],[!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]}": "php"
    }
}
```

In example above, all files up to 30 characters long without extension will be associated with `php`.

You can shorten this entry with multiple pattern lists combined in one line, such as `{...}{...}{...}`. The example below works like the previous one, but it is much shorter:

```json
{
    "file.associations": {
        // all files up to 30 characters long without extension will be associated with `php`
        "{[!.],[!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]}{[],[!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]}{[],[!.],[!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.][!.]}": "php"
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you want to set this up for files in a directory where you only have root access, or you don't want to create a `.vscode` folder in it, you can create a rule in your user `settings.json` with the path in this rule, e.g.:

```json
{
    "file.associations": {
        "/etc/**/{[!.],[!.][!.],...}": "shellscript"
    }
}
```

Another solution for files in specific directory is to use multiple rules:

```json
{
    "file.associations": {
        "/etc/**/*": "shellscript",      // this rule will work on all files
        "/etc/**/*.list": "debsources",  // and this one to exclude .list files
        "*.list": "debsources"           // due to this rule won't work for .list
                                         // files in /etc/** directories
    }
}
```

This is because a more specific rule takes precedence over a more general rule.