# VS Code does not recognize shebang for bash

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, shebang

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907947/6830983), VS Code is supposed to recognize shebangs in files without extensions, and associate those files with the Shell Script language mode. In that post, they say it works for the shebang `#!/bin/sh`. However, this doesn't seem to work for shebang `#!/bin/bash`. I need to use Bash for my project, otherwise I would just switch to the Shell Command Language (sh). Also, I cannot add the `.sh` extension to the end of the filename, because I'm submitting a batch job to a supercomputer, and the filename needs to be named using the following pattern: `jobname-batch`. Is there a way to configure VS Code to have the same behavior for extension-less Bash scripts than for extension-less Shell Command Language scripts?

Edit:

@Julia suggested in the comments to make the file executable, and that got it working. :) Thanks!

Comment: Does the file have the executable bit set (i.e. `chmod +x jobname-batch`)?

Comment: Did you try closing and opening the file again?

Comment: Hi @Julia, I don't think it'll be necessary to make the file executable for vscode to recognize its type. I tried using VS Code v1.46.1 on mac, and the editor was able to recognize the file type without making the file executable.

Comment: I see. You could give `touch jobname-batch; chmod +x jobname-batch; code -w jobname-batch; chmod -x jobname-batch` a shot. This will create a file, make it executable, open VS Code and wait for it to close, then remove the executable bit.

Comment: @Julia, the files were not executable. I made them executable, and they were recognized correctly :) Thanks!

Kartik Chauhan, I did try closing an opening the file without success. I'm running VS Code on a remote Linux host (my client is also Linux), and it looks like VS Code in Linux does need the script to be executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "set the executable bit" trick works, but I'm not sure where that information is stored or if it's persisted across reboots. I just remembered a better solution: file associations!

Just add this to `project/.vscode/vscode.json` (the key should be the name of the file):

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "jobname-batch": "bash"
  }
}
```